# Склонение сложносоставных числительных по падежам и родам

Tags: числительные

Как правильно склоняются сложносоставные числительные по падежам и родам? К примеру, имеем число 2345, "две тысячи триста сорок пять". Мне нужно некое правило, которое однозначно определяет склонения слов "два", "тысяча", "триста" и т.д.

Т.е. муж.род, дательный падеж - "двум тысячам триста сорок пяти" или "две тысячи триста сорок пяти"?

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался.
Количественные числительные склоняются полностью, т.е. "двум тысячам триста сорока пяти пехотинцам"; при этом род зависит от показателя порядка, т.е. для сотни, тысячи - род женский, для миллиарда - мужской, для единиц - род счетного слова (в примере - пехотинец). Падеж аффектит одинаково все слова.
Порядковые числительные отличаются тем, что склоняется только последнее слово, "две тысячи триста сорок пятому пехотинцу". При этом показатели порядка "склеивают" числительные в одно слово, и получается нечто типа "почетный приз выдан четырёхсотвосьмидесятичетырёхмиллиардному жителю".

Answer (score 0):

Первый вариант однозначно неправильный, если склонять все разряды, то без исключения: двум тысячам ТРЁМСТА СОРОКА пяти.

Comment: 1. правильно ли я понимаю, что категория рода влияет только на последнее слово, в то время как вспомогательные слова, типа "тысяча" явно аффектят "свои" слова своим родом? Наиболее яркий пример - это "одна тысяча сорок один".
2. В каких случаях падеж влияет на все разряды, в каких - только на последнее слово?

Answer (score 0):

Интересно, но интересно то, что многие дикторы сейчас неправильно произносят сложные числительные. Включите новости и послушайте. Как мне известно, как наступил 2001 год, дикторы произнесли: Сейчас у нас двадцать первый век, год двести первый. 
Вот что я запомнила... Замечательно, что кто-то умеет и правильно говорит! Но, всё чаще встречаются ошибки. Мы привыкли числа (три, девятьсот) записывать цифрами, а это неправильно! Возможно употреблять их только в точных науках: матикатике! Запомните, друзья!

Comment: числа записываются цифрами, и это правильно.

Comment: Не знаю, что есть "матикатика", но слово мне понравилось.

Comment: Смеялась до слёз, уже плачу. Объясните мне, пожалуйста, кто может, в чём смысл данного выражения  "мы привыкли числа (три, девятьсот) записывать цифрами, а это неправильно! Возможно употреблять их только в точных науках" ? Ради бога, никого не хочу обидеть...

Answer (score 0):

*"почетный приз выдан четырёхсотвосьмидесятичетырёхмиллиардному жителю"*. fisher, Вы не заметили, что противоречите сами себе. В Вашем примере склоняется каждая часть составного числительного. Потому что это вовсе и никакое не числительное. Дело в том, что по лексическому значению слова "тысяча", "миллион", "миллиард" относятся к числительным, но по грамматическим признакам это существительные: они имеют род, изменяются по падежам и числам по  парадигме имен сущетвительных. От них образуются прилагательные "тысячный" ,"миллионный"... А количественные числительные, сливаясь с этими прилагательными в одно слово, умудряются при этом склоняться. Ваш пример, ещё подобные случаи: восьмисотшестидесятидевятилетний, тристасорокапятидневный.  А вот у порядковых числительных действительно склоняется только последнее слово. Поэтому коробит слух, когда приходится слышать "двухтысячидвенадцатый год".

Comment: поправляю сама себя: ТРЁХСОТсорокапятидневный
Да, непросто это - склонять числительные!!

Answer (score 0):

2345 И. две тысячи триста сорок пять. Р. двух тысяч трёхсот сорока пяти. Д. двум тысячам трёмстам сорока пяти. В. две тысячи триста сорок пять. Т. двумя тысячами тремястами сорока пятью. П. о двух тысячах трёхсот сорока пяти.
Постановка вопроса неверная: сложносоставные числительные.Такого разряда числительных нет. Это - составное количественное числительное. Составные количественные числительные состоят из двух и более слов и пишутся раздельно. Каждая его часть склоняется по падежам. Но о роде не может быть и речи.

Answer (score 0):

1. Числительные бывают ПРОСТЫЕ (два, двенадцать), СЛОЖНЫЕ  (двести) и СОСТАВНЫЕ (двести двенадцать). В сложных существительных склоняется каждое слово. Составные числительные состоят из нескольких числительных (простых, сложных, а также грамматических существительных – тысяча, миллион)
2. Среди числительных можно выделить количественные и порядковые числительные.
   КОЛИЧЕСТВЕННЫЕ числительные изменяются по падежам, а ПОРЯДКОВЫЕ числительные являются грамматическими прилагательными и изменяются по числам, родам и падежам (первый, первая, первые).
3. Существуют  еще СЛОЖНЫЕ СЛОВА (существительные и прилагательные)  на основе числительных: пятилетний, пятиклассник. Числительное обычно стоит в Р.п.
4. Отдельную группу составляют ПОРЯДКОВЫЕ ЧИСЛИТЕЛЬНЫЕ на основе грамматических существительных «ТЫСЯЧА, МИЛЛИОН, МИЛЛИАРД»,   по структуре являются СЛОЖНЫМИ СЛОВАМИ, сравнить:  пятиметровый – пятитысячный (нет разницы). Способ образования – чистое сложение: пяти+тысячный.

ВСЕ ЭТИ СЛОВА ВЕДУТ СЕБЯ ПО-РАЗНОМУ, ИХ НЕЛЬЗЯ СМЕШИВАТЬ.

(1)  2345 – две тысячи триста сорок пять – СОСТАВНОЕ КОЛИЧЕСТВЕННОЕ ЧИСЛИТЕЛЬНОЕ, изменяется по падежам каждое слово: к двум тысячам тремстам сорока пяти.

(2) 2345-ый – две тысячи триста сорок пятый – СОСТАВНОЕ ПОРЯДКОВОЕ ЧИСЛИТЕЛЬНОЕ (грамматическое прилагательное) – изменяется по родам, числам и падежам только последнее слово:  в две тысячи триста сорок пятом году.

(3) 2345 -летний  город  – двухтысячетрехсотсорокапятилетний город -  СЛОЖНОЕ ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНОЕ включает  соединительную гласную Е  для слова «тысяча» и формы Р.п.  для количественных числительных. В двухтысячетрехсотсорокапятилетнем  городе – родительный падеж для всех основ, окончание выражает изменение  сложного прилагательного по родам, числам и падежам.

(4)«Почетный приз выдан четырёхсотвосьмидесятичетырёхмиллиардному жителю». 
Это ПОРЯДКОВОЕ ЧИСЛИТЕЛЬНОЕ (грамматическое прилагательное), но его структура на основе слова «миллиард» соответствует СТРУКТУРЕ СЛОЖНОГО СЛОВА. Это означает, что все входящие числительные имеют форму Р.п., далее  опорное прилагательное МИЛЛИАРДНЫЙ.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (КАТЕГОРИЯ ОДУШЕВЛЕННОСТИ-НЕОДУШЕВЛЕННОСТИ)

1. Ряд числительных (ДВА, ТРИ ЧЕТЫРЕ, ОБА-ОБЕ И СОБИРАТЕЛЬНЫЕ ЧИСЛИТЕЛЬНЫЕ) могут выражать категорию одушевленности-неодушевленности при сочетании с существительными, то есть для одушевленных существительных В.п. совпадает с Р.п., а для неодушевленных  - с И.п.:

встретил  (кого?) двух девушек, двоих студентов, обоих всадников

прочитал (что?) две книги, отдыхал двое суток, купил оба стола

1. Неопределенно-количественные существительные выражают одушевленность-неодушевленность непоследовательно: Отдыхающие видели нескольких (или несколько) акул.
2. Из сказанного следует, что очень немногие числительные могут выразить одушевленность-неодушевленность, и, разумеется, к ним не относятся составные числительные. Соответственно, в большинстве случаев В.п. совпадает с И.п.

Comment: Остался один момент : озвучить числительное 2345 в В.п. с одушевл. сущ. @Oktay привел свой вариант, но есть сомнения)
*Военкоматы мобилизовали 2345 призывников*.  
Какое слово является главным в сочетании **2345 призывников** (В.п.) и *строит вокруг себя* все остальные зависимые слова? С большим удовольствием жду Вашего обстоятельного анализа, заранее благодарю.

Comment: @Дерзкий grantum. Благодарю. Я всё понял и сделал поправку.

Comment: Я усложню вопрос. Пишут, что в составных колич. числительных склоняется каждое слово, но здесь еще вмешивается одушевленность/неодушевленность предметов!  
Мобилизовали **две тысячи триста сорок** (одного, два/двух, три/трех, четыре/четырех) призывника/призывников. Эти тонкости в справочниках обходят стороной, так как же правильно - *мобилизовали ... сорок четыре призывника* или *... сорок четырех призывников*? 
Отменяется ли в таких случаях деление на одуш./неодуш., вот в чем загвоздка.  
Если можно, поделитесь конкретной ссылкой, пожалуйста!

Comment: Дерзкий grantum.Мне кажется, что Ваше внимание в счетном обороте направлено на существительное, но оно не имеет отношения к выражению одушевленности. Одушевленность могут выражать только числительные, и мы наблюдаем именно за их падежом.

Comment: Итак, призываем на службу: одного (Р.п.) призывника,  двух (трех, четырех, Р.п.) призывников. А вот составные числительные не выражают одушевленности, даже если в их составе есть числа 2, 3, 4: мобилизовали двадцать два призывника, сорок четыре призывника, две тысячи триста сорок пять призывников. Все числа в составном числительном стоят в И.п. - было бы странно, если бы они имели разные падежи (одни _Р.п., другие - И.п.).

Comment: Мобилизовали **двадцать одного** призывника. Какой падеж? Винительный? Там у Вас, выше, тоже не Р., а В.п.

Comment: Исправляю неточную запись: призываем на службу: одного (В.п. = Р.п.) призывника, двух (трех, четырех, В.п. = Р.п.) призывников. Запись расшифровывается так: В.п. совпадает по форме с Р.п., одушевленность выражена. Мобилизовали двадцать два  (В.п. = И.п.)призывника. 

С "двадцать одним" хуже. Один - грамматическое прилагательное, здесь возможно исключение.Мобилизовали двадцать (В.п. = И.п.) одного (В.п.=Р.п.) призывника. Получается, что в составном числительном числа имеют разные падежи - в виде исключения. Возможно, сказывается влияние: двадцать первого - двадцать одного.